# Scan Document on Client Side in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-development-server

I want to scan document on client side in asp.net web application. Is there any right path to use Scanner on Client machine in asp.net?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you can't control a local resource like a scanner. Sorry =/

Comment: if it's an intranet, you could always try using a supplementary application? [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/493333/Client-Side-Printing-Scanning-in-NET) could help you en route. 
Another option, is simply providing your users to upload a pdf. That does oblige them to firstly scan and save it to their local device.

Comment: The case is user will enter and save the details of customer then scan their documents and save to DB. scan is mandatory for their documents, plz suggest

Comment: I would propose to your user(s) to scan the documents first (locally) then upload en save the details of the customer. =/

Comment: If this answer suffices to your question, do not forget to mark it as answered!

Comment: still waiting for any logical reply

Comment: the only logical answer I can propose in your case is the following steps: a) user scans document and saves to local PC. b) User uploads the file to the db using a form, also entering the other needed data. Then the form can parse all to the db. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Is it possible to call windows Application into web application , it might be solve the problem?

Comment: You could try the steps found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916925/how-to-launch-an-exe-from-web-page-asp-net). Good luck!

Comment: If windows application called something like this then task can be achive

Comment: Another option is to create a windows application, that sends the data to a web service. This way you can scan the file directly from within the winforms, and send all data to your webserver. If this answer resolves your issue, do not forget to mark it as such

Comment: yes, This can be solve my problem,but I need a proper demo for this , how to access win Form in Services.

Comment: That would be another issue ^_- 
you _could_ find some info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564352/how-do-i-programmatically-send-information-to-a-web-service-in-c-sharp-with-net) on how tu use webservices

Answer (score 1):

You can't access Scanner. Users can scan their documents and save it as image. then that file we can take via asp.net application.